# Order Custom Field by Price

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, order

First of all i've found [numerous](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value), [topics](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155320/sorting-meta-value-as-integer-doesnt-work), [and](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ordering-user-query-by-numeric-custom-field), [issues](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38657/order-by-numeric-value-for-meta-value) about ordering a `WP_Query` by its custom field value, but somehow all the proposed solutions don't seem to work for me.

I have a custom field `Price` from which i want to order my results. The problem is that when i use `21.00` as input, i also get the results where the Prices are `2095.00`, `209.00`, `208.00` etc. Also, when i use (for example) `658.00` as input, i get `65.00` as result

The values of `Price` are imported from an XML feed and come with the point as delimiter, so i add those to my input as well.

Here's my query

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 8,
    'paged'             => $paged, 
    'offset'            => 0,
    'post_type'         => 'travel',
    'land'              => $_GET['slug'],
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters'  => true, 
    'meta_key'          => 'price',
    'meta_type'         => 'NUMERIC', 
    'meta_value'        => $_GET['price'], 
    'meta_compare'      => '<',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value', // I also tried meta_value_num
    'order'             => 'DESC'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And i load the content with jQuery like so

```
var priceValue = $('<input>',{
    'type' : 'number', 
    'id' : 'maxPriceVal', 
}).on('change', function(){
    $('#results').load(queryPath+'&price='+$(this).val()+'.00');
}).insertAfter('#price');
```

Anybody any idea what's causing the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `'meta_value_num' => $_GET['price']` AND `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same result :(

Comment: What about `'meta_type' => 'decimal'` ? You could also try to eliminate the problem by multiplying the original value with 100 before saving and dividing by 100 when processing the value in templates.

Comment: Nope, that still gives me values of 1099, 1095 when i use 110 as input

Comment: Okay, I just noticed that you pass the `$_GET` variable directly into `WP_Query`. First, this might be unsafe without sanitizing the values. But more importantly you can not be sure that the the value is of the desired type, in your case `float`. You can check the data type by `print_r( gettype( $_GET['price'] ) )`. Use `floatval( $_GET['price'] )` to make your input a float var that WP_Query can work with...

Comment: Whatever i use, `floatval()` or `intval()`, the output is a sting and the result is the same (92 and 919 by an input of 92). And i know about the sanitising, and i know it's not an excuse, but i'm still local so would've put it in there before going online ;)

Comment: The result of `floatval()`should never be a string. If the value can not be parsed as a float the function returns `0`. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php). Could you report what is printed if you do: `$price = floatval( $_GET['price'] ); print_r( gettype( $price ) );`.